# Return string numpy array from process

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-multiprocessing

I have two processes created using multiprocessing. The first filters a group of files and the second one takes the filtered files and processes them (the second process takes a subset from the first set of files). I am using a numpy array to save the files names (in the filtering function I use numpy indexing for selecting the files). I need to use multiprocessing because I am using a progress bar with tkinter to show the progress of the program.

How can I share this numpy array of file names between the processes? I am guessing that I should not use the indexing function I used for selecting the files, but to iteratively fill the array (using a loop) so I can use an Array object from the multiprocessing library. Is this the only option?

Comment: You could use `q = multiprocessing.Queue()` to pass objects between the two processes. The first process puts a new "filtered file" in the queue when it's ready using `q.put()` and the second grabs it with `q.get(block=True)`. This will make the second process wait for results from the first one, although I don't know which one is the fastest in your case.

Comment: @Guimoute the first process computes a value from each file and the filtering is based on the average of all values. So I would prefer to pass the array once the first process is finished.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from doing that, just place the `q.put()` at the end of the first process I guess. Which process updates the progress bar?

Comment: I tried that and I got "None" instead of the array. The main process updates the progress bar

Comment: It's tough to help further without seeing your code.

Comment: I took your suggestion. I was using one queue to update the progress bar and share the array, I was saving both variables in a tuple and I guess that is why I was not able to get the array. You made me think in creating another queue to save the array only, and it worked! thank you. Do you want to answer so I accept it? @Guimoute

Comment: Good, I am glad it worked for you :) I'll see tomorrow if I have time to write it properly.